# GET request with long URLs

Tags: php, get, html-email, file-get-contents

I need to do a get request, which will in turn send emails. The thing is that everything is passed in the url including the html content. I am facing two problems here :

1. As the email content can be arbitrarily long, it is showing Too large URI, when I run through the browser. Also file_get_contents is also showing invalid aqrguement error.
2. When I urlencode the HTML, I am losing the inline style tag and so the mail is not displayed properly.

I am accessing a url something like

> http://s.domain.com/send_email.php?to=to@to.com&from=from@from.com&subject=subject&html=urlencodedhtml

This is working if the HTML content is not that much long and I am using this to rewrite the links in the content to some other urls for enabling tracking. How can I pass large strings through URL.

Comment: Any reason it **needs** to be GET? If you explain why you're trying to do it this way, it may be easier to find an alternative solution.

Comment: A GET request isn't an appropriate request here. You should be doing a POST, where the message is in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Using a GET request will always set very strict limits of how much data can be passed to a script.

Depending on client and server, the amount of data that can be sent is usually no more than 8 KB. Most servers support URLs of up to 8 KB length. On client side MSIE and Safari will only support about 2 KB, Opera about 4 KB and only Firefox handles 8 KB. This, of course, is still not enough for your use case.

So I'm afraid the only possible solution for that will be doing a POST request instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that PHP setups with the suhosin patch installed will have a default limit of 512 characters for get parameters. So your URl wouldnt support if user give loong data and Although bad practice and a piece of cake for Hackers.

Check [Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#101469)

For this you can use **POST** and can receive all the variables on the second page.

for e.g:

```
$to = 'abc@xyz.com';
$subject = 'Your subject here'
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Your Site <abc@abc.com>' . "\r\n";
$message = 'Your Html goes here';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: okay, I am using cURL with POST request now. But now also the HTML is stripped. I mean there is no style tag. How can I prevent this ?